# What is the difference between need and necessity?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

I was asked what the difference between need and necessity was by a non native speaker. It was in the context of the name of an article to do with global warming, i.e "The need/necessity for....". I was completely stumped and googling it only produced speculative answers.

In my mind a necessity is an absolute requirement, for example food and water is a necessity for survival. I would have said that a need is a requirement but maybe not an absolute one. For example, there is a need for an umbrella when walking outside in the rain.

Could you please give a definitive answer, if there is one?

**EDIT** - Attempting to address Edwin Ashworth's need for signs of research.

The Oxford English Dictionary defines [need](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125752?rskey=olzHxm&result=1#eid) and [necessity](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125650?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=hufoc7&) as follows

> Need - Necessity, requirement.
>
> Necessity - Constraint or determination by some external force; an instance of this.

In Fleischer's 1804 book ["English Synonymous Or the Difference Between Words Esteemed Synonymous in the English Language: Useful to All who Would Either Write and Speak with Propriety and Elegance"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3MxmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=difference%20between%20need%20and%20necessity&source=bl&ots=vcHTVAvUGs&sig=j-uUz0ViujZbsMXrT1xTgUW-mZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfzdSro-DUAhWPJlAKHdE_CQQ4FBDoAQg-MAU#v=onepage&q=difference%20between%20need%20and%20necessity&f=false), need and necessity are given by

> Need and necessity relates less to the situation of life than the other three words [in the context of poverty, indigence and want]; but more to the relief we expect or the remedy we seek, with this difference between the two that need seems less pressing than necessity.

although this is both contextual and dated. I am struggling to find other reliable sources, hence my post on this website.

Comment: Food is a necessity for survival. I need food to survive. I don't see much of a difference between these two other than the fact that they are not always interchangeable within a given sentence.

Comment: @NVZ Do you think that an umbrella is a necessity when walking outside in the rain? I would have thought that it was a need, but not a necessity, as you are able to walk outside in the rain without an umbrella. Does this make sense or is it a circular argument? In which case I guess I am arguing that needs are subsets of necessities which would address your first comment.....

Comment: The umbrella is not a need. The complication is that definitions are allowed to broaden ('An Acme umbrella is a must!') / You need to show signs of research you yourself have done.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'You need to show signs of research' - is that a necessity?

Comment: @1QuickQuestion You don't **need** an umbrella to walk outside in the rain. You need legs and an able body. You need an umbrella to prevent yourself from getting wet, and in that case an umbrella is a necessity.

Comment: A *need* is something that is needed. A *necessity* is something that is necessary.

Comment: @peerless I've now close-voted as OP has not added any evidence of research. A couple of dictionary definitions / example sentences for each word would suffice; they don't need to give a definitive answer to the question, but would in that case further highlight the problem.

Comment: 'These people have great needs' obviously doesn't sound right if written 'These people have great necessities'. Synonymity is almost always a vast topic even when only two synonyms are being considered. But 'need' and 'necessity' are certainly synonyms: 'New types of antibiotics are a n..., not merely a useful addition to the armoury.' // 'Needs' are sometimes graded; 'Maslow's hierarchy of needs is a theory in psychology proposed by Abraham Maslow in his 1943 paper "A Theory of Human Motivation".' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs)] The fact that ...

Comment: Maslow used 'needs' rather than 'necessities' in his work, and that his work is quite famous, means that the term 'need' has broadened in this usage (unlike 'necessity'); according to his theory, some 'needs' are more necessary than others. This is true in common speech too; 'I need a lift to work' isn't strictly true without qualification. The verbal usage tends to broaden the nounal; 'necessitate' is very rare in conversation and hasn't the corresponding meaning, so the broadening is not the same.

Comment: Necessity is the mother of invention. Need is an alias she uses, a very useful one since it allows her to be more versatile, like sometimes function as a verb instead of just a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several reference works have attempted to draw distinctions between *need* and *necessity* since Fleisher did so in 1804. From George Crabb, [*English Synonymes Explained, in Alphabetical Order*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l30PAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA381&dq=%22derange+and+disconcert+are+employed+for+such+things%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLzezPxbTdAhVrCDQIHXw1BzgQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22Necessity%2C%20need%22&f=false) (1816):

> ***Necessity*** respects the thing wanted; ***need*** the person wanting. There would be no ***necessity*** for punishments, if there were not evil doers ; he is peculiarly fortunate who finds a friend in time of ***need***. ***Necessity*** is more pressing than ***need*** : the former places in a positive state of compulsion to act ; it is said to have no law, it prescribes the law for itself ; the latter yields to circumstances, and leaves in a state of deprivation. We are frequently under the ***necessity*** of going without that of which we stand most in ***need***.

From George Graham & Henry Reed, [*English Synonymes Classified and Explained*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CGsPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA330&dq=further+farther&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt2u-S3ebTAhWEjFQKHTrMA7sQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22need%20is%20exigent%22&f=false) (1847):

> ***Need*** is exigent and pressing; ***necessity*** is stern and unyielding. **Necessity** demands; **need** requires. Those who are in **necessity** are in the lowest degree of poverty, and have no means of supplying their commonest wants; those who are in **need** are in a temporary difficulty, from which a moderate help will relieve them. **Necessity** forces us to act for ourselves; in our **need**, we require the assistance of our friends. We may manage to do without what is needful, but hat is necessary cannot be dispensed with.

From Charles Smith, [*Synonyms Discriminated: A Dictionary of Synonymous Words in the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UNREAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA541&dq=%22need+and+necessity%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOi4mbi6jwAhVfAp0JHT_QABcQ6AEwA3oECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22need%20and%20necessity%22&f=false) (1910):

> **NEED** (A.S. *nead*, *want, compulsion*) relates directly to the urgency of the demand, and indirectly to the absence of supply. Want is commonly absence of mere possession; **need**, absence of means of action. As they express states, **NECESSITY** (Lat. *necessitatem*) is stronger than **NEED**, for whereas **NEED** is negative, **NECESSITY** has a positive and compelling force. A man is in **need** of food. Under some circumstances there is **necessity** for immediate action. **Need** is pressing, **necessity** unyielding. **Need** is the strongest degree of requirement, **necessity** of demand. In the phrase of the English Psalms, "See that such as are in ***need*** and ***necessity*** have right," the second term is an augmentation of the first. **Need** may be temporarily and easily removed; **necessity** is more lasting and less remediable. We **need**, in cases of difficulty, the advice and support of friends; but lacking this, we are often impelled, by **necessity**, to decide and act for ourselves.

From James Fernald, *English Synonyms, Antonyms, and Prepositions*, thirty-first edition (1914):

> ***Necessity*** is the quality of being necessary [elsewhere in the book defined as that "which must exist, occur, or be true; which in the nature of things can not be otherwise"], or the quality of that which can not but be, become, or be true, or be accepted as true. ***Need*** and *want* always imply a lack; ***necessity*** may be used in this sense, but in the higher philosophical sense ***necessity*** simply denotes the exclusion of any alternative either in thought or fact; righteousness is a ***necessity*** (not a ***need***) of the divine nature. ***Need*** suggests the possibility of supplying the deficiency which *want* expresses; to speak of a person's *want* of decision merely points out a weakness in his character; to say that he has ***need*** of decision implies that he can exercise or attain it. As applied to a deficiency, ***necessity*** is more imperative than ***need***; a weary person is in ***need*** of rest; when rest becomes a ***necessity***, he has no choice but to stop work.

From *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942):

> **Need, necessity, exigency** come into comparison when they denote a state or condition requiring something as essential or indispensable, or the requirement itself. ***Need*** implies pressure and urgency arising  either from external or internal causes or forces: it may merely suggest the call of  an appetite or demand for emotional or intellectual satisfaction (as, he is in ***need*** of food; the child suffers because of a ***need*** for affection; he felt the ***need*** of an education), or it may imply circumstances, such as great poverty, a severe storm, a threat of war, actual hostilities, or the like, that show a lack of or create a demand for something indispensable to the well-being, protection, security, success, or the like, of those concerned (as, to provide food and lodging for those in ***need***); the European war has taught Americans the ***need*** for a two-ocean navy; "So at the threat ye shall summon—so at the ***need*** you shall send Men"—Kipling). **Necessity**, though often interchanged with ***need***, usually carries a far stronger suggestion of an imperative demand or of  a compelling cause; as, telephone me in case of ***necessity*** (i.e., if in very great ***need***); "as soon as war is declared, every nation or institution must subordinate all other considerations to the  ***necessity*** of victory" (*Inge*). "When a legal distinction is determined ... between night and day, childhood and maturity ... a point has to be fixed or a line has to be drawn ...  to mark where the change takes place. Looked at by itself without regard to the ***necessity*** behind it, the line or point seems arbitrary" (*Justice Holmes*). Sometimes, however, in order to enforce this implication, ***necessity*** is qualified by some such term as compelling; as compelling ***necessity*** drove him to seek financial aid. ***Necessity*** may also apply to a compelling principle or abstract force inherent in nature or in nature in in the constitution of a thing and inevitable in it operations or inescapable in its results; as, there is no logical ***necessity*** apparent to the conclusions you have reached; physical ***necessity*** lies behind our nee of food and drink; "One of the unhappy ***necessities*** of human existence is that we have to 'find things out for ourselves'" (*T.S. Eliot*).

The updated version of this dictionary, *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) uses different examples to illustrate the distinctions it makes between *need* and *necessity*, but the wording of the distinctions themselves is virtually unchanged from the 1942 edition.

From Bergen Evans & Cornelia Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1957):

> **need; necessity; want** ***Need*** and ***necessity*** are nouns which designate a lack or a demand which must be filled. ***Need***, a word of Old English origin, has connotations which give it a strong emotional appeal) (*A friend in **need** is a friend in deed. I had most **need** of blessing;, and "Amen" / Stuck in my throat. O, reason, not the need! Our basest beggars / Are in the poorest thing superfluous*). ***Necessity***, a word of Latin origin, is more formal and impersonal; or objective. Though much stronger than ***need*** in expressing urgency or imperative demand, it is less effective in appealing to the emotions (***Necessity** is the mother of invention. The art of our **necessities** is strange, / That can make vile things precious*). ...

From William Morris & Mary Morris, *Harper Dictionary of Contemporary Usage*, second edition (1985):

> **necessity/need** ***Necessity*** can be followed by either "of" or "for," as in "There is no ***necessity** for* (or *of*) alarming him at this time." An infinitive is never used after ***necessity***; rather, ***need*** is used with an infinitive, as in "There is no ***need*** *to* alarm him at this time." Since ***necessity*** and ***need*** are synonymous, there is little logic to this. It is simply a matter of idiom.

An Ngram chart of "no necessity for" (red line) versus "no necessity of" (blue line) versus "no necessity to" (green line) for the period 1700–2019 suggests that "no necessity to" has been in idiomatic English use for centuries:

[image]

But the key point in Morris & Morris's treatment of the entry for *necessity/need* is the assertion that "*necessity* and *need* are synonymous." Coming after the numerous efforts to distinguish the two terms from one another, this matter-of-fact statement that the two words mean the same thing is a bit startling—but I think it is true for most English speakers.

Some nuanced speakers and writers seem clearly aware of a greater intensity, longevity, or motivating force of *necessity* in comparison with *need*. Others are more fitful in their awareness of any distinction in sense or overtone between the two words—or simply use them interchangeably.

In trying to distinguish between close synonyms, you should bear in mind that most people who grow up speaking a language acquire their understanding of what the words mean more or less osmotically—especially in the case of common words that they are likely to have encountered (and used themselves) from a fairly early age. They don't start out by consulting a dictionary and trying to apply the meanings they find there to the situation they want to talk about. For this reason, it is difficult to estimate with any confidence the extent to which real-world usage ever abided by the definitions and distinctions that lexicographers and usage experts recorded and prescribed through the years.

Answer (score 1):

> **Need** has **one** syllable, **necessity** has **four**.

So, if both work, use **need**.

Otherwise choice depends to a large extent on one’s experience of usage, which defies consistent logical explanation. Examples (with hints at explanations in parentheses) include:

> “It’s an absolute necessity” (emphatic)
>
> “Necessity is the mother of invention” (conceptual)
>
> “My needs are few, my wants are endless” (didactic simplicity)
>
> “Basic necessities” (stock phrase)
>
> “God shall supply all your need” (biblical)

After twenty years or so, you’ll get the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is not intended to be definitive, and I have not found supporting evidence, however as a reasonably good English speaker, I think it's a subject/object thing:

> I need you to survive. You are a necessity for my survival.
>
> My car need needs fuel. Fuel is a necessity for my car.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but something can “fill a need”. Nevertheless, you might be on to something if you can tease out the nuances and exceptions.